# How can one convert this to coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I was using js2coffee but it doesn't seem to translate because I get an `unexpected identifier`.

```
$.fn.wait = function( ms, callback ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        window.setTimeout((function( self ) {
            return function() {
                callback.call( self );
            }
        }( this )), ms );
    });
};
```

My coffee version:

```
$.fn.wait = (ms, callback) ->
  @each ->
    window.setTimeout ((self) ->
      ->
        callback.call self
    (this)), ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First clean up your JavaScript version so that it isn't trying to be overly clever and difficult to read; the inlined self-executing function really doesn't do anything for you except make the people maintaining and reading your code hate you:

```
$.fn.wait = function( ms, callback ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var _this = this;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            callback.call(_this);
        }, ms);
    });
};
```

That's less noisy and easier to grok at a glance. The `var _this = this` trick is generally replaced by a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) in CoffeeScript so we're left with this:

```
$.fn.wait = (ms, callback) ->
    @each(->
        fn = () => callback.call(@)
        setTimeout(fn, ms)
    )
```

Yes, parentheses are often optional in CoffeeScript but *optional* and *forbidden* are different words so I tend to include the parentheses to make the structure easier to see. You could also skip the `fn` variable with something horrific like this:

```
setTimeout(
    => callback.call(@)
, ms)
```

or this:

```
setTimeout (=> callback.call(@)), ms
```

but throwing an extra variable into the mix is, IMO, much easier on the eyes.

Demos:

- CoffeeScript: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/y44Fp/
- JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TVkMh/

Answer (score 0):

Use the fat arrow (`=>`):

```
$.fn.wait = (ms, callback) ->
  @each ->
    window.setTimeout( =>
      =>
        callback.call( this );
    , ms)
```

It compiles to:

```
$.fn.wait = function(ms, callback) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var _this = this;
    return window.setTimeout(function() {
      return function() {
        return callback.call(_this);
      };
    }, ms);
  });
};
```

> The fat arrow => can be used to both define a function, and to bind it
>   to the current value of this, right on the spot. This is helpful when
>   using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, for creating
>   iterator functions to pass to each, or event-handler functions to use
>   with bind. Functions created with the fat arrow are able to access
>   properties of the this where they're defined.

(Source: http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow)

Comment: Use the cleaned up version by @mu-is-too-short, it's much nicer :)